# Disabling Landscape Printing in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have a Windows Form that, when a button is clicked, prints out two (or more) pages. For simplicity's sake, I will assume I have two documents to be printed: PrintDocumentA and PrintDocumentB. PrintDocumentA is to be printed in landscape mode, while PrintDocumentB is to be printed in portrait mode. Both of them share the same PrintDialog - for design issues, it has to be this way.

The code I use to call them for printing is as follows:

```
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDocumentA.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
        PrintDocumentA.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        PrintDocumentA.Print()

        PrintDocumentB.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
        PrintDocumentB.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
        PrintDocumentB.Print()
End If
```

But the odd thing is, even though I've disabled it, PrintDocumentB still comes out in landscape.

Now of course I could place PrintDocumentB before PrintDocumentA in the code, like so:

```
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDocumentB.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
        PrintDocumentB.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
        PrintDocumentB.Print()

        PrintDocumentA.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
        PrintDocumentA.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        PrintDocumentA.Print()
End If
```

And this would work - for the first printout. But when the same button is clicked again, now B still comes out in landscape mode. My guess is somehow the Landscape = True value is being used globally, and B also taps into it. I have to exit that particular Windows Form and open it again for the printouts to come out in the correct orientations.

How do I resolve this issue?

---EDIT---

For more clarity, this is the only code I've got before the above snippet:

```
Dim PageSetup As New PageSettings
    With PageSetup
        .Margins.Left = 50
        .Margins.Right = 50
        .Margins.Top = 100
        .Margins.Bottom = 75
        .Landscape = False
End With
```

Comment: You don't need 2 documents, just a Boolean that you toggle and check right before you use it.

Comment: @OneFineDay what does that mean exactly? I need to print two different documents that's why I have two.

Comment: Are you using a `pageSetupDialog` control?

Comment: @OneFineDay not quite sure what that meant... See edits though?